# Python Import Error when working with GoogleAppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-import

I have Google AppEngine SDK installed(at /usr/local/google-appengine), and the toy App can be launched and run with GoogleAppEngine Launcher with no issue.

However, I have some standalone scripts (testpbuf.py) in the app folder that I want to run with

```
$python testpbuf.py
```

then I got Python Import errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testpbuf.py", line 3, in <module>
    from google.appengine.api import files
ImportError: No module named appengine.api
```

The script is trying to import AppEngine API and protorpc modules..

What's going one here? I have the SDK included in my PATH and I have no problem invoking from terminal. Any insights? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You need to get all the libraries inside the SDK added to your path. This can be done as follows:

```
import dev_appserver
dev_appserver.fix_sys_path()
```

Running code outside of the SDK web-server for things other than tests isn't likely to be that useful to you though ... when it runs on appengine, it has to be via WSGI.